# Unfortunately, Application m-jadwal has stopped

Tags: java, android

I'm build an application to Parsing and display data from MySQL using json. I'm using tabbed activity for the navigator. When I am build the apk there is no error.But when i'm running my application I received an error as **Unfortunately, M-jadwal has stopped.**

Project File : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9286Ffx-sgybkVmZXVpQV8zZFk/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code file :

**Gradle App**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lamberto.m_jadwal"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.lamberto.m_jadwal;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
    private AdapterFish mAdapter;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        // Refresh Start
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jadwal_batal);
        // Swipe Refresh Layout
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new AsyncFetch().execute();
            }
        });
        //Make call to AsyncTask
        new AsyncFetch().execute();
    }
    private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL("http://sayangoppa.com/ibn/jadwal.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<DataFish> data = new ArrayList<>();

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataFish fishData = new DataFish();
                    fishData.matkul = json_data.getString("matkul");
                    fishData.waktu_batal = json_data.getString("waktu_batal");
                    fishData.waktu_pengganti = json_data.getString("waktu_pengganti");
                    fishData.dosen = json_data.getString("dosen");
                    fishData.ruang = json_data.getString("ruang");
                    fishData.alasan = json_data.getString("alasan");
                    data.add(fishData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Tab1 jadwal_hari_ini = new Tab1();
                return jadwal_hari_ini;
            case 1:
                Tab2 jadwal_batal = new Tab2();
                return jadwal_batal;
            case 2:
                Tab3 info_kampus = new Tab3();
                return info_kampus;
        }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Jadwal Hari Ini";
                case 1:
                    return "Jadwal Batal";
                case 2:
                    return "Info Kampus";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.lamberto.m_jadwal.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_jadwal_batal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swifeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fishPriceList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Please tell what is the problem and how to avoid that. Thanks in advance**

**Error log :**

```
04-03 19:43:57.785 2998-2998/com.example.lamberto.m_jadwal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.lamberto.m_jadwal, PID: 2998
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.lamberto.m_jadwal.MainActivity$AsyncFetch.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:193)
                                                                                 at com.example.lamberto.m_jadwal.MainActivity$AsyncFetch.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:83)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Add error log to your question

Comment: post your app level gradle and error log both.

Comment: When build the apk there is no error. But when I run the application there is an error showed "Unfortunately, M-jadwal has stopped."

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan provide the error log first...and app level gradle code.

Comment: @DkThakur there is no error log. But when I started the application the error showed.

Comment: You can download the project here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9286Ffx-sgybkVmZXVpQV8zZFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan how is this possible that there is a error but no error log.If your device is connected the PC then you will have error log too.

Comment: If you will not provide error log and more info like gradle code your problem could not be solved.

Comment: @DkThakur I already input the error log

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan as i am thinking this is because of your gradle please provide your gradle code .

Comment: Edited. I have input gradle code

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan why you are setting two layouts in one Activity class

Comment: I am new in android developing. So what should I do ?

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan Please refer the B.shruti answer i think this will work.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provide logcat yet there might be more than one error.
However you are setting your contentView twice

Remove these lines

```
// Refresh Start
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_jadwal_batal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is arising because SwipeRefreshLayout is returning null because it is in a separate xml file(activity_jadwal_batal.xml) not in your main xml.
So first inflate this xml with the help of layout editor and then get this SwipeRefreshLayout, use like below -

```
View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.activity_jadwal_batal, null);
 mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)convertViewfindViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);
```

Here ctx is your activity context.

Comment: Please edit your code with (SwipeRefreshLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);

Comment: what should I do with that code? Sorry, I am new in android developing

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan simply replace with your code super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jadwal_batal);
        // Swipe Refresh Layout
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh); to given.

Comment: Using this instead of context

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. But it's cannot resolve symbol 'ctx'. What must I do ?

Comment: Using (this keyword)  instead of ctx  View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_jadwal_batal, null);

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_jadwal_batal);
// Swipe Refresh Layout
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);
```

AND

```
// Setup and Handover data to recyclerview 
mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
```

to

```
//make this global  
View convertView = null;

//with SwipeRefreshLayout
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_jadwal_batal, null);
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);


//with RecyclerView
mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
```

Comment: You are doing your code in wrong manner.First of all do some research how to design layouts and how to use them.

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan do the same for recyclerview like View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_jadwal_batal, null);
mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);

Comment: Change this part ?  // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList); mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan only replace with this  // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);